# JSTree add image after title using json data

Tags: javascript, jstree

I am using jsTree and I want to add images after the title of the node using json data
Here is the sample image. I want to add Add section and Add Element image after the title Report Title

[image]

Comment: Have you had a thought of https://github.com/deitch/jstree-grid?

Comment: yes I've gone thru the jstree-grid link, the only prob with that is, I want the image just after the title ie no space between the title and the image. The title if too long will be cut off, but want the image just after the title

Comment: If jstreeGrid is the only solution would you use it? I think you can use html inside node's name.

Comment: I can do that with html for sure, but want to do it with json data

Answer (score 0):

Radek opened an issue on the jstree-grid page https://github.com/deitch/jstree-grid/issues/26

What I am having a hard time understanding is, it doesn't look like you want a grid; it looks like you want the node label itself to also have some html? Or is the problem that you *do* want the html, but you want the input to be json that gets converted to html?

Comment: Drat, I meant for this to be a comment on your post, not an answer. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

For older version `jsTree 1.0-rc3` we need to set `html_titles : true` to render node title as html content instead of plain text.

Example:

```
buttons = "<strong><a class='delete' href='javascript:;'>x</a><a class='extend' href='javascript:;'>+</a></strong>"
$("#demo1").jstree({
  "json_data" : {
    "data" : [
    {
      "data" : "A node" + buttons,
      "metadata" : { id : 23 },
      "children" : [ "Child 1", "A Child 2" ]
    }
    ]
  },
  "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data", "ui"],
  "core": {html_titles : true}
});
```

Hope it may help someone who is struck in older version of `jstree`, just like me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to append an Icon to a JSTREE's node text using JSON Data. I am using Microsoft's fabric.css for the icon library. (Using jstree 3.3.1 & Bootstrap for the margin class)

```
//Create JSON Obj
var obj = {
    id: 1, 
    text: "MY NODE TEXT" + "<i class='ms-Icon ms-Icon--check ml-2'></i>", 
    state: { opened: true },
    li_attr: { "class": "myCustomClass"}
};
 
// Append to array
var JSONDATA = [];
JSONDATA.push(obj);

//Push to JSTREE
$('#jstree').jstree(true).settings.core.data = JSONDATA;
```